# Use regular expression to pull a specific select clause from SQL statement using .Net

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression to return a part of a sql statement. An example:

```
a.column1,
(select b.column1, 
b.column2, etc) as column2,
a.column3
(select c.column1, etc) as column4,
(select d.column1, 
d.column2, 
d.column3, etc) as column5,
a.column6,
(select e.column1, etc) as column7
```

What I want given string such as "column5" return the select statement that generates column5 "select d.column1" etc. I have tried the following:

```
\(((?:.|\n)*?)\)(?=\s{1,}AS\scolumn5)
```

but it returns the select statement from column 2 all the way to column5. Is there anyway to make my regex statement lazy and only return the select statement immediately before "column5"?

Comment: Do you mean to say "...Only return the select statement immediately before "column2"?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to match `column5` in your current regex, `column2` isn't in it..?

Comment: if you are asking about the expected result given my sample regex, i expect the statement to return the select statement before column5. If i replace column5 with column4 it should return the select statement before column4

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, but why not something like `^.*?column5`? (assuming statements don't cross multiple lines)

Comment: @certainperformance. yes my current regex statement is looking for the select statement before column5.

Comment: @CertainPerformance no the select statement can be very long and cross multiple lines. that is why i included \n within the "(" & ")" characters.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It looks like the `as column#,` always occurs at the end of one column-generator and before another, so might you match non-commas until you come across the column you want?

Comment: @CertainPerformance what do you mean?

Comment: Eg `[^,]+column5`

Comment: Oh...select statements always have a "," after every column. So there would be "," after  every "x.column#" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
@"^(?<select>\(select[^)]*\))\sas\scolumn5,?$"
```

You should set the `'MultiLine'` and `'IgnoreCase'` options.

The regex starts by start of line, then creates a named capturing Group (`'select'`), which will end up containing just the 'select' statement (between parentheses).

Then it matches a left parenthes '`(`' followed by the text `'select'`, followed by any number of `non-right-parenthes`, followed by a White Space, `'as'`, a White Space and the text `'column5'` and finally an optional comma '`,`' and end of line.

**How to use**:

Create your regex like this:

```
new Regex(@"^(?<select>\(select[^)]*\))\sas\scolumn5,?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

You can access the `'select'` Group by using: `Match["select"].Value;`